# Python: algorithm to find four numbers in an unsorted array which satisfy desired sum

Tags: python, algorithm

Given an array of unsorted positive integers and a desired sum, what is the best way to print in ascending order 4 distinct 0-based indexes of elements in the array that add up to an input sum, if such indexes exist.
If there are multiple solutions I just need to print the lowest one according to the lexicographical order

Example input:

```
A = 3 2 1 4 5 7 6 9 7 8
S = 30
```

Example output:

```
5 6 7 9
```

Comment: What code have you tried? What does it do that is unexpected/incorrect?

Comment: I was approaching this as a dynamic programming problem. Am I correct that there is not a way to solve this in O(n) time?

Comment: There is certainly no O(n) way to do this if the list were unsorted. If the list were sorted, I'm still not 100% sure - I'd have to think about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [36]: A
Out[36]: [3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 7, 6, 9, 7, 8]

In [37]: S
Out[37]: 30

In [38]: N
Out[38]: 4

In [39]: for tup in itertools.combinations(A,N):
   ....:     if sum(tup) == S:
   ....:          for perm in itertools.product(*[[i for i,num in enumerate(A) if num==n] for n in tup]):
   ....:              print(*sorted(perm))
   ....:             
5 6 7 9
6 7 8 9
5 6 7 9
6 7 8 9
```

Complexity:

- `for tup in itertools.combinations(A,N)` costs (O(`|A|` choose `N`))
- `sum(tup)` costs O(`N`)
- `[[i for i,num in enumerate(A) if num==n] for n in tup]` costs O(`N*|A|`)
- `itertools.product(*[[i for i,num in enumerate(A) if num==n] for n in tup])` therefore costs O((`N*|A|`)!)

So, you end up spending (`|A|` choose `N`) * [`N` + {(`N*|A|`) * (`N*|A|`)!}], which is bounded below by `|A|!` and above by `|A|^2 * |A|!`

Comment: Can you quantify your solution time with big O notation please?